# While loops with dependent If statements in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a program that creates binary numbers from base 10 numbers base on `n`. I use `t` as a counter for my while loop.

I am trying to fill a list with the output from this so `n`must equal `t`. How can I do this without undermining my while loop and if statements?

```
keyList = []
binList = []
n = 0
i = 0
t = 0


while (t <= 255):
    ## 128
    if n < 128:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 128:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n - 128

    ## 64
    if n < 64:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 64:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n - 64

    ## 32
    if n < 32:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 32:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n - 32

    ## 16
    if n < 16:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 16:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n -16

    ## 8
    if n < 8:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 8:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n - 8

    ## 4
    if n < 4:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 4:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n - 4

    ## 2
    if n < 2:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 2:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n - 2

    ## 1
    if n < 1:
        binList.append(0)
        n = n

    elif n >= 1:
        binList.append(1)
        n = n - 1
    print(n)
    t = t + 1
```

Currently, I am not able to get `n` and `t` to equal each other without impacting the outcome of the code where I only get 0.

Comment: It would be helpful to see all the code. I don't think I can figure out what's wrong based on only the code snippets that you've provided.

Comment: @iamchoosinganame Ok, here it is.

Comment: Python already has functions that do this, but I assume you are working on an assignment. There is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: If you are trying to convert `t` to binary in each loop then you probably want `n = t` at the top of the loop body.

Comment: @KennyOstrom this actually isn't an assignment. I'm just starting to get into python and thought this would be a good project.

Comment: If you invert your algorithm to look at the lowest bit instead of some manually defined highest bit, it is a lot easier. Use n%2 to check if the next bit is set, and n //= 2 to advance to the next bit.

Comment: @Duncan I know I tried, but I still get only 0s. Thanks.

Comment: You need to pick between a loop (which can handle any size number with modulo and // base) or a series of if statements to handle each bit separately. Doing both together doesn't make sense.

Comment: it is important to note that after `if x<y` you can use `else` instead of `elif` to catch all other scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop style that you have above is not exactly pythonic. `for t in range(x)` is a typical way to iterate through a range of numbers.  You have effectively unrolled a loop into a series of highly repetitive if statements, which I've rolled up into an inner list. `n` must be initialized for each value of t, and lastly I took the next step to add the binary string to the keyList.

```py
keyList = []
binList = []
n = 0
i = 0

value_list = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
for t in range(255): # iterates through 0 to 255
    n = t
    binList = []
    for v in value_list: # iterates over list in order
        if n < v:
            bit = 0
        else:
            bit = 1
            n = n - v
        binList.append(bit)
    keyList.append("".join(map(str, binList)))
```

Comment: binList is for taking the binary number that time through, then it would be added to keyList so that key list would be filled with all 256 numbers. Also, I tested this and you still only get 0 rather than the proper binary. Is the if statement for bit a valid statement?

Comment: @ForestCayden I've added a completed solution for your issue

Comment: Would you mind explaining the last line of the code?

Comment: str function converts the int to string, map applies str (or any other single input single output function) to all of the entries of binList, join is a function of a string that outputs a string of the entries supplied joined by the string whose join is called (in this case an empty string, but it could be ', ' to insert a comma and space).